# how to set VSCode when i execute a c++ program the screen doesn't disappear immediately

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

I know i can use "system pause" or "getchar" to make the screen doesn't disappear immeadiately when i use VSCode to execute my c/c++ program,but it's really troublesome.I want to know if i could let the program pause automaticly just like 
VS and other IDE.

Comment: VS execute window disappears immediately without `system("pause");` too ?

Comment: F5 immediately,ctrl+F5 remain

Answer (score 1):

VSCode have the Intergrated terminal (Ctrl + `), you can run and see console output there.
Even in Visual Studio C++, if you do not set break point, the console app will terminate and disappear when reach return 0 in main.

Comment: In Visual Studio the console will remain after main terminates if you run (CTRL-F5) instead of debug (F5)

Comment: @bolov but it run the app without debugger.